# How to store encryption keys in .NET

Tags: .net, encryption

Where and how to store ecryption keys? After a quick search i dont know how to store an encryption key without coding it or prompting the user.

A common scenario: a desktop application installed on different pcs, with access to a server database. The database has ecrypted data, ecrypted with an unique key and random IV.

Either if i choose to use DPAPI to store the unique key in the registry, or to use Key Containers, or any other method, how to store it without prompting the user or doing it by code, wich could be easely decompiled using Reflector, ILSpy? I have never use ILSpy or any other decompiling software before, and i am very surprised on how easely your code can be read. So, how to create/store/"install" the key, so the application could use it for encrypt/decrypt?

I know, i dont understand it, and i have to read more :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a secure encryption strategy, you need to use an encryption algorithm that doesn't need to ask the user for keys.

You describe a 2-tier architecture where client PCs access the database directly.  Can you introduce a webservice?  Allow the webservice to access the encrypted data, and use SSL to communicate between client PCs and the webservice.

With this approach, you only configure the database encryption key once (on the server) and data is secured between client & server using an industry standard approach.  (You can use [WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082(v=vs.110).aspx), or you can use a variety of server-side technologies to make a REST webservice)

Comment: Woah, thank you. It seems to be a very good option! And what about simple non client-server applications? how they normally manage key storing, at installation level or in "run once / first time run" methods?

Comment: A simple windows-based app should use the built-in [Data Protect API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata(v=vs.110).aspx) directly.  It's not as secure, but it's the recommended approach.